# Bind9 MX record - Bind9 add the server name to the MX record

Tags: dns, mx-record, bind9

I have set up 2 Bind9 DNS servers with Webmin. Both on dedicated servers with a static ip. A master server and the slave is added as a cluster slave server to the master server in the bind dns server config menu.

***This is the setup:***

### **gw-ns1.mydomain.com gw-ns2.mydomain.com**

1. Created a master zone for mydomain.com with a A record pointing
   to the mail server - mail.mydomain.com and a MX record for the
   domain mydomain.com - host: mydomain.com ; Exchanger
   mail.mydomain.com.
2. Created another master zone for another domain - lets call it
   otherdomain.com . Added a MX record also pointing to
   mail.mydomain.com

Now here comes the problem. When you query the ns server it gives you a wrong MX record. It takes the mail.mydomain.com and puts the in the back of the name so it looks like this: mail.mydomain.com.otherdomain.com instead of mail.mydomain.com. When you check the record on the master server it looks correctly. But on the slave server it also shows the wrong MX record: mail.mydomain.com.otherdomain.com.

Have anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/apa/dot.html

Comment: It actually says that under the text form:
(Absolute names must end with a .)

So all I had to do is put a . at the end of the record :)

Thank you Sir for your help!

Comment: Now you can answer yourself and close the topic (it's still shown as active).